# IE6 friendly reminder

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I remember a while back I came across a Javascript that replace a webpage with a friendly message when one's browsing in IE6. The message mainly says IE6 is not suitable for browsing this website along with links to the latest Firefox, Safari and Chrome download. I can't remember the site or the keyword that I google for. Anybody has seen something similar?

Comment: Try opening youtube.com in IE6, you will get similar message

Comment: Most sites use conditional comments to deal with this as opposed to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several. Check out:

[IE6 Update Warning: 7 Ways to Tell Your Site Visitors to Upgrade](http://garmahis.com/tools/ie6-update-warning/)

Comment: "because IE6 compatible development requires unreasonable amount of resources spent" SO unprofessional

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any site in particular (although I thought Google did this actually).  However, if you're trying to reproduce the same effect on your site, what you want to do is use conditional comments:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments

The short version is:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
  <p>Only less than IE 7 will see this</p>
<![endif]-->
```